# VB.NET - Split Number into multiple ones

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I was workin on a small tool lately for checking and editing MS SQL Databases. But now I'm standing in front of a wall. I want to split a big number from a column to several small ones. For example I have the number 195872323 and I want it to be shown as **195 Diamonds 872 Gold 323 Platinum** idk. How can I split this number into this kinda String?

Thanks to everbody for helpin me.

Comment: you need some criteria for splitting the strings.  Your example has 3 strings of 3 characters each, which might be what you are looking for, or it could be the last digit in the string sums to the last digit in the first string.

Comment: I want the 3 last, the 3 following then and then every number that follows. For example last three numbers at last, next three from the end as three and everything after them it doesn't matter.

Comment: You need to put that into the question, also you appear to have a typo "3 last" doesn't make sense, I assume you meant first three...but either way, your requirements don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the string you want, use this. I should add that Stack Overflow isn't strictly a code writing service, but it was quick and easy.. You original number is originally the essentially number of platinum -  assuming 1000 platinum per gold and 1000 gold per diamond

```
Private Function SplitToCurrency(x As Integer) As String
    Dim diamonds As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(CDec(x / 1000000)))
    Dim gold As Integer = CInt(Math.Truncate(CDec(x - diamonds * 1000000) / 1000))
    Dim platinum As Integer = x - diamonds * 1000000 - gold * 1000
    Return diamonds.ToString & " Diamonds " & gold.ToString & " Gold " & platinum.ToString & " Platinum"
End Function
```

Diamonds are calculated by dividing the original number by 1,000,000 and removing the decimal

and so on for the rest.